# Caffe prebuild binaries on window

Tags: visual-studio-2015, build, caffe

I use pre-build binaries on vs 2015, when I build my project, I encountered with this error: error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-gd-1_61.lib'

Comment: You either have no boost 1.61 library on the computer or caffe build does not see its path.

Comment: What binaries are you using? In my case: see "### Install the caffe dependencies " section in README.md file

Comment: I use pre-build binaries vs 2015, CPU only, python 2.7, and all dependencies download: libraries_v140_x64_py27_1.0.1.tar.bz2 ( https://github.com/willyd/caffe-builder/releases/tag/v1.0.1), I try another version but still encountered error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-gd-1_xx.lib'.